# make can't find Qt headers when compiling project on the command line

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm trying to compile a Qt Creator project on the command line. Here's what I did.

```
$ qmake
$ make
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DALLOWSYNCING -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. -o main.o main.cpp
In file included from ./model/videostream.h:4:0,
                 from ./model/videostreamersession.h:4,
                 from view/videoplayerwindow.h:4,
                 from main.cpp:3:
./model/videoframe.h:5:18: fatal error: QImage: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

It looks like `make` can't find the header files for Qt-related classes. How do I tell `make` where it can find them using an additional parameter or environment variable? I noticed some search paths are included by default, but in my environment they're located in `/opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include/`.

---

As requested, my PRO file. It was initially generated by Qt Creator so it's nothing out of the ordinary.

```
QT += core gui

TARGET = output
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += # Trimmed for brevity
HEADERS += # Trimmed for brevity

# Special build flags
DEFINES += ALLOWSYNCING

# These libraries are required for the program to operate
LIBS += -ljrtp -ljthread
```

Comment: Looks correct. Do /usr/include/qt4/QtGui and /usr/include/qt4/QtGui/QImage exist? (maybe you have somehow a qmake distro package installed, but not the -dev one?) If you want to use the SDK, add its bin/ dir to the PATH as synthesizerpatel suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CXXFLAGS="-I/opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include/" CFLAGS="-I/opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/include/" LDFLAGS="/opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/lib" make

However, you're probably on a mac I'm guessing.. In which case you should just export QT_DIR=/opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/, and add /opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/bin to your PATH and that should jiggle everything into place once qmake runs.

Comment: It's QTDIR, and setting it shouldn't be necessary. Just add qmake to the PATH.

Comment: Running `/opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/bin/qmake` directly seems to work. Thanks!